# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.training.training' has no attribute 'SummaryWrite

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def add_layer(inputs,in_size,out_size,activation_function=None):
with tf.name_scope('layer'):
    with tf.name_scope('weight'):
     Weights = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([in_size,out_size]),name='W')
    with tf.name_scope('biases'): 
     biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1,out_size])+0.1,name='b')
    with tf.name_scope('Wx_plus_b'):
     Wx_plus_b = tf.matmul(inputs,Weights)+biases
    if activation_function is None:
      outputs = Wx_plus_b
    else:
      outputs = activation_function(Wx_plus_b)
    return outputs

x_data = np.linspace(-1,1,300)[:,np.newaxis]
noise = np.random.normal(0,0.05,x_data.shape)
y_data = np.square(x_data) - 0.5 + noise

#define the placeholder for input
with tf.name_scope('inputs'):
xs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,1],name='x_input')                        
ys = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,1],name='y_input')

#add hidden layer
l1 = add_layer(xs,1,10,activation_function=tf.nn.relu)

#add output layer
prediction = add_layer(l1,10,1,activation_function=None)


# error between prediction and real data
with tf.name_scope('loss'):
 loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(ys-prediction),
                 reduction_indices=[1]),name='loss')
with tf.name_scope('train'):
 train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1).minimize(loss)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()



sess = tf.Session()
writer = tf.train.SummaryWrite("C:\\Users\\duke\\Desktop\\tensorflow      example\\",sess.graph)
sess.run(init)
#fig = plt.figure()
#ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
#ax.scatter(x_data,y_data)
#plt.ion()
#plt.show()


#training step
for i in range (1000):
     sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={xs:x_data,ys:y_data})
      if i % 50 ==0:
     # print(sess.run(loss,feed_dict={xs:x_data,ys:y_data}))
      try:
         ax.lines.remove(lines[0])
      except Exception:
         pass
      prediction_value = sess.run(prediction,feed_dict={xs:x_data})
      lines = ax.plot(x_data,prediction_value,'r-',lw=5)
      plt.pause(0.1)



sess.close()
```

I currently use tensorflow to build a simple 3 layers NN, and I want to use tensorboard to show the gragh. but when I run the module, it shows:  AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.training.training' has no attribute 'SummaryWrite'. I am really confused....

Comment: Just replace it with tf.summary.FileWriter ;)

Comment: Thx a lot, but I can not see the Graph on the tensorboard web page..It shows: no graph definition file was found

Comment: I have run your code and graph is there! First make sure that summary file is generated in the location you specified. I think Tensorboard cannot find your summary file therefore showing nothing! Save your summary to a safe and easy to access directory, check its existence and then use "tensorboard --logdir=your summary address" to read it. Your code need no more modification. At least in the last Tensorflow version.

Comment: Also, it `has no attribute 'SummaryWrite'` because what you intended to type was `tf.train.SummaryWriter`. However, `tf.train.SummaryWriter` has been deprecated in favor of `tf.summary.FileWriter`.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by @Neal, SummaryWriter is no longer exported into the train module, as it was deprecated.See [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/34df7ee6f5a8f931d2433dc7e6e739bc880a35ea/tensorflow/python/training/summary_io.py#L31).

Instead use `tf.summary.FileWriter`